# How to create a collection from JSON data in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I have the following J SON data. How to sum balance of the following collection?

```
"_id" : ObjectId("592595a1bca1350220027666"),
"user_account" : "5-5XX4XX-X06",
"Xns" : {
        "Xn" : [
                {
                        "date" : "2015-09-01",
                        "narration" : "ATM/CASH WDL/01-01-10/17:48:45/0",
                        "amount" : "-2500.00",
                        "category" : "Others",
                        "balance" : "110578.04",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("592595a1bca13502200276ca")
                },
                {
                        "date" : "2015-09-04",
                        "narration" : "EBA//20100104081107",
                        "amount" : "-7206.12",
                        "category" : "Others",
                        "balance" : "103371.92",
                        "_id" : Object Id("592595a1bca13502200276c9")
                }
```

Comment: how many customers info you have and how many accounts info you have? Do you have a json file. Does a single json object contains CustomerInfo and Account data?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by :

```
mongoimport --db <db-name> --collection <collection-name> --file ~/location/<file-name>.json
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB offers `mongoimport` tool for that. For example:

```
mongoimport -c people -d example --mode upsert --file people-20160927.json
```

**C** for collection, **D** for database. [Read more here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) And don't forget your JSON should be a valid [extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)

Comment: I want to store through collection

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: I want to create collection for json file.

Comment: Alright you can do that with -c option of mongoimport as I've described in the answer

Comment: 'mongoimport' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: You have to be in the bin directory of where you've installed mongodb.

Comment: Then you need to contact with your INFRA to access it.

Comment: And how could do that

Comment: Access denied means you don't have necessary rights to execute mongoimport, do you have a system administrator ? Or don't you have sudo rights on your system ?

Comment: Thanks! Sercan Ozdemir